# Redis - store CSV as value/blob?

Tags: python, redis

I am scraping (legally) .csv files every night.  ~20% grow by one line on any given night.

I'd like to store the whole csv as a "blob" in redis, rather than deal with FS. Is that possible, even with new lines within and such?  How?

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) is a good start. However, I recommend taking a look at [Should I use redis to store large number of binary files in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786395/should-i-use-redis-to-store-large-number-of-binary-files-in-redis)

Comment: Thanks, Moayad, familiar with both links.  This is 6000 files, each in the 1.0K to 3.0K range.  Way, way smaller footprint.